# how to insert image in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, asset-pipeline

Using Rails, I am creating my first web-site. And I have a problem like this: I can't insert an image in my page (index.html.erb).

I put an image named "main.png" in directory "app/assets/images", and wrote that:

```
<img src="main.png">
```

But my image isn't displayed correctly. What I'm doing not right?

Comment: In description you mentioned 'main.jpg' but in img tag you are calling 'main.png'. Notice the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the provided helpers by Rails to "automagically" detect paths, fingerprints, ...:

```
<%= image_tag "main.png" %>
```

Anyway, I recommend you to read the asset pipeline guides to understand how the assets works in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use Rails helpers as [markets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3033649/markets) pointed out.

By the way, the name of the image file should be the same you use as the parameter of *image_tag* method. You are referencing your image as *main.png* when the image file is *main.jpg*

```
<%= image_tag "main.jpg" %>
```